# How can I call multiple values from the element with the same name with xpath?

Tags: xpath

I want the last two `<dd>` elements so that the output will read, `Talstrasse 2A 01816  Berggiesshübel`

here is the html snippet

```
<dt>Öffnungszeiten:</dt>
<dd>10:00 - 17:00</dd>                                                                    <dt>Veranstaltungsart:</dt>
<dd> Herbstmarkt</dd>                                                    <dt>Veranstaltungsort:</dt>
<dd> Besucherbergwerk "Marie Louise Stolln" Berggiesshübel</dd>                                                    <dt>Strasse:</dt>

<dd>Talstrasse 2A,</dd>  
                     
<dt>PLZ / Ort:</dt>

<dd> 01816  Berggiesshübel </dd>
```

here is the suggested xpath my software gives me.

```
//div[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " container ")]/section[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " row event-details ")]/div[1]/div[3][contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " bg-normal pal mbm ")]/div[1][contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " row ")]/div[1]/dl[1][contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " dl-horizontal event-detail-dl ")]/dd[6] | //html/body/div/section/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/dl[1]/dd[6]
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The last two `dd` elements would be `(//dd)[position() >= last() - 1]`. In XPath 2.0 and higher you can get a single string using the `string-join` function e.g. `string-join((//dd)[position() >= last() - 1], ' ')`.